# Find the number of islands in a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the number of islands (groups of connected 1s) in a 1D binary numpy array. I've been searching for a while, but can only seem to find solutions for matrices, so curious if there is a faster alg.

Example:

```
x = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0])

result = find_islands(x)
```

Here, the result would be `2`. Indices of islands does not matter. The size of the input array is always the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to create your own algo, or find an existing one?

Comment: Think about which local configurations in the array indicate "start of island" and count those.

Comment: `result = repr(x).count("0, 1, 1")`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen This will fail in these cases: `101`, `010`, `1101`... etc.

Comment: @Anwarvic the question is about a binary numpy array

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I apololgize... this will fail in these cases: `[1, 0, 1]`, `[0, 1, 0]`, `[1, 1, 0, 1]` ...etc.

Comment: @Anwarvic I know, but the question is about a 1D binary array.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the starts of islands. A start of an island is a zero followed by a one or just a one as the 0th element. Those you can count like this since numpy treats one and zero as true and false

```
def find_islands(x):
    return np.sum(x[1:] & ~x[:-1]) + x[0]
```

For the provided test cases including the ones from the comments it seems to work.

```
find_islands([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]) --> 2 
find_islands([1, 0, 1]) --> 2
find_islands([0, 1, 0]) --> 1
find_islands([1, 1, 0, 1]) --> 2
```